# DataGrid with checkbox event

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, datagrid

now consider i have this simple datagrid

[image]

here is my xaml

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Height="362"
          Margin="10,55,0,0"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="362"
          x:Name="table">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

code that fire this info

```
        MySqlCommand cmd = m.getmodel("select * from "+equip+" where stored="+place);
        MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable data = new DataTable(equip);
        dataAdapter.Fill(data);
        table.ItemsSource = data.DefaultView;
```

now here is the point , whenever i click this checkbox on the left , i need to send the imei code of same row to c# code , i need to store the imei of checked rows , any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a `DataColumn` of type `bool` to the `DataTable`, the `DataGrid` will automatically generate a `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`, which is linked to the `DataTable`.

```
private void InitializeDataTable()
{
  MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

  DataTable data = new DataTable(equip);
  dataAdapter.Fill(data);

  var checkBoxColumn = new DataColumn("Select", typeof(bool));
  data.Columns.Add(checkBoxColumn);
  checkBoxColumn.SetOrdinal(0); // Move column to the beginning

  foreach (DataRow row in data)
  {
    row["Select"] = false;
  }

  table.ItemsSource = data.DefaultView;

  data.ColumnChanged += OnColumnChanged;
}

private void OnColumnChanged(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
{
  var imei = e.Row["imei"];
}
```

Comment: hello , i have tested your code , ot gives me that output https://imgur.com/TehiDVX , for unknows reason i cant change the check box , and next how can i create a handler that takes a value from the same row ?

Comment: You need to initialize the rows. I've updated the answer.